# Why does my div overflow when there is clearly enough space?

Tags: css, html, overflow

Here is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>A+Tec</title>
<style type="text/css" >
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #ABEBC1;
  position: fixed;
}

#nav {
  width: 720px;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
}

.buttons {
  height: 25x;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: #ABEBFF;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  float: left;
  margin: 0px 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="nav">
  <div class="buttons">
  </div>
  <div class="buttons">2</div>
  <div class="buttons">3</div>
  <div class="buttons">4</div>
  <div class="buttons">5</div>
  <div class="buttons">6</div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I have the wrapper with the divs inside. There is clearly enough space for all the divs yet one of them overflows to next line as in picture:

[image: 1]

I have no idea what is wrong but the div with 6 in it has overflowed onto the next line but the wrapper is plenty big enough to accomodate it. Can you please help me?

Thanks

Comment: 150 * 6 = 900, 900 > 720, mystery solved.

Comment: `nav` is only 720, which makes it smaller than the total `buttons`

Comment: Oh right. I did not consider nav. Thanks

Comment: Don't forget you also have 10px of margin on either side of these buttons as well, so it's not just 150 * 6, it's 170 * 6 (because margins on floats do not collapse.) So when you adjust the width of `nav`, keep that in mind :)